# Handle duplicate message consumed on Kafka Rebalance or application reload

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Currently, I have set up a spring boot application, it has 3 pods runnings.

And I have a Kafka consumer that processes a particular task for 20 minutes.

When the Kafka rebalances during that time then the same is consumed again, so I have set the Redis key whenever the message comes first, so when it rebalances it checks that key exists and discards that event as that old process is still running.

But now I have a scenario that a particular pod that is running can get restarted anytime, no when the application restarts and the same message is consumed that then, I want that message to be reprocessed, but as the Redis key exists it discard this event, but the old process is not running.

I have to re-process the message on application restart and discard it in case of Kafka rebalance. How can I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid the rebalance by increasing `max.poll.interval.ms`
2. Kafka is not really suited for this kind of long-running task; consider moving the task to a DB (or even Redis) when received from Kafka, and process from there.

Another solution would be to set `max.poll.records` to 1, then pause the listener container before running the task on another thread, and then resume the container when the job finishes.

Pausing the container will keep the consumer alive and avoid the rebalance.

Comment: I added another solution.